Why does parallel axis theorem only work when one axis has gone through the center of mass?
By setting the origin at the center of mass, and the coordinate of P axis being (a,b) the formula should be derived by the following method:
$$I_{CM} = \Sigma m_{i}(x_{i}^2 + y_{i}^2)$$
$$I_{P} = \Sigma m_{i} [(x_{i} - a)^2 + (y_{i} - b)^2]$$
$$I_{P} = \Sigma m_{i}(x_{i}^2 + y_{i}^2) + (a^2+b^2)\Sigma m_{i}$$
$$I_{P} = I_{CM} + Md^2$$
My question is that why can't you repeat that process but with two arbitrary axis? Since the moment of inertia requires the sum of the product of mass and distance from axis squared of every particle, then the center of mass should not matter right?

Why would you even want to do that?

How did you cancel your cross terms in the summation? :^) Think about why you can go from your second line to your third line.

A simple thought experiment should convince you that $I_{CM}$ is not an ignorable component of the calculation.  First of all, one key aspect of $I_{CM}$ is that the center of mass is the exact location for which the integral $\int r^2 dm$ is minimized, for every infinitesimal mass $dm$ at a location $r$ from the CM.
Now let's say, for example, that you have a long thin rod of mass $m$ and length $l$.  The "in-plane" $I_{CM}$ is equal to $\frac{1}{12}m l^2$.  About one of the ends, call it point A, we can apply the 2D parallel axis theorem to compute $I_A = \frac{1}{3}m l^2$.  What if we want to shift the axis in question to the other end of the rod (call it point B) without considering the CM? A naive and wrong process would conclude that $I_B = I_A + m l^2$. When in fact we know that $I_B = I_A = \frac{1}{3}m l^2$.
Even if you were going to choose an axis that was very close to $A$ and were OK with a little math error, how would you know whether to add or to subtract the $m d^2$ term?  It would depend if you were moving toward or away from the CM.
Another more mathematical way to think of it.  Consider the parabola $y = C + x^2$. Here, $y$ is like the MOI and $x$ is like the distance between axes. C is analogous to $I_{CM}$.  If you know the value of $y_A$ at some point $x_A$, and you want to calculate the value $y_B$ at $x_B$ where $d = x_B - x_A$, how do you go about doing that?  Well, you can write $y_B = y_A+\Delta y = (x_A + d)^2 + C$ and simplify to get $\Delta y = d^2 + 2dx_A$.  Which isn't the same as saying $\Delta y = d^2$.  The ONLY time that is correct is if $x_A$ = 0, which is the analogous value of $x$ at the COM.
So, for better or worse, the center of mass is a critical reference point when using the (2D) parallel axis theorem and computing moments of inertia.  You can't do the calculation without it.
